# Commerce License not de-activating when expired

Tags: commerce

I'm using commerce license on one of my website. And I found out that some of the licenses that are expired didn't get de-activated.

As you can see, in the image below. License 113, 114, 115 should be inactive. But they are still Active (Actief). In the last column you will see that the expiring dates are past today (08/22/2016).
[image: License overview]

Using the modules Ultimate Cron and View Queue I'm able to see that the Commerce License module is adding the queue.
[image: Queue]

I also look in my logs but no errors are found. Does anybody know what the problem can be or what my next step in searching for the problem can be?

Thanks in advance,
Zeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the basic Drupal cron didn't call the license sync. Using Ultimate Cron I was able to make this work.